# Transformer characteristic for impedance matching in RF

Tags: rf, transformer, impedance, matching

In an rf impedance matching circuit it is assumed that transformer is ideal or large enough. I just wanted to know the quantification of "large enough" (which parameter is large with respect to what)

Question is in context of RFIC not discrete elements. I want to know the design specific practical value. say I have two impedance z0 and z1 depending on these what should be the practical value(thumb rule) of transformer, and how to approximate(calculate) it.

Comment: What is the source of this information ?

Comment: This question was asked in a classroom session of Radio-frequency Integrated Circuit design at IITM. , which at that time i was completely unaware of. Actually it refers to quality factor. And I wanted to know what should be the practically utilized high value for this.

Answer (score -1):

Transformers can be easily used as impedance transformation, but as the reactance depends on frequency hence the solution only employs on a narrow band. Also it should be taken care that inductance of coil should be much higher than the coil resistance. As we know that any resistance that coil possesses is source of energy loss. In short the transformer should have a high quality factor, where quality factor is defined as (energy stored/energy dissipated per cycle).

Comment: There problems with both your question and answer. Your question refers to "large enough" yet this means nothing without a link to a document that puts this phrase into context. As for your answer, firstly inductance DOES NOT depend on frequency. Secondly you appear to think that only resistance is transferred across a transformer - this is also untrue.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote inductance rather than reactance $$2\pi f L$$ transformer also have capacitance and they needed to be resonated out, and i answered in context of RFIC where resistance always is an issue, due to noise and energy dissipation.